# For loop that creates a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to store training and testing errors with the corresponding `test_size` in a dictionary, because I want to create a test/training error figure. Unfortunately the for loop is not working. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? (instead of a dictionary storing them in a pandas df is also fine).

```
array = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
dicto = {}

for i in array: 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = i)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)   
    test = clf.score(X_test, y_test) 
    train = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    dicto[i, test, train]

print(dicto)
```

I get the following error:

> KeyError: (0.1, 0.89473684210526316, 0.91176470588235292)

Comment: What do you want your keys and values to be?

Comment: I think I get a keyerror because I request a dictionary object that is not in the dictionary..

Comment: Post the minimum script that we can run with expected input and output. You're looking up a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: I would like to have a key that is my test_size and the values are the test and train variabeles (these are my test and training errors)

Comment: You are right Bahrom. I would like to add them to the dictionary.. but it is not working this way

Answer (score 2):

You're never assigning the value in the dictionary:

```
dicto[i, test, train] # This is trying to lookup a key of (i, test, train), which doesn't exist yet.
```

Try this instead:

```
dicto[i] = (test, train) # map test and train variables to test_size, which is i
```

Comment: When reading the dict, you should look up based on test size, so something along the lines of `dicto[test_size]`

Comment: Thanks Bahrom! This works for me :) You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Is that, what you want?

```
dicto[i] = test, train
```

Comment: I think so! Do you add something to a dictionary with the line you wrote?